# Openssl does not work with c++ . Says rsa.cpp:1:25: fatal error: openssl/rsa.h: No such file or directory #include <openssl/rsa.h>

Tags: c++, openssl

I'm trying to build a c++ application that requires some asymmetric encryption . So I decided to use openssl RSA and successfully installed on my machine which is windows 10 . But when I compile it(i have MinGW installed) , I have error

```
rsa.cpp:1:25: fatal error: openssl/rsa.h: No such file or directory
 #include <openssl/rsa.h>
```

Comment: How did you install OpenSSL?  How are you building your code?  You will need to tell your toolchain where to find the OpenSSL headers and libraries, and how you do that depends on what toolchain you're using.

Comment: The folder containing the open `openssl` folder needs to be in the list of folders that your compiler looks for headers.

Comment: ***successfully installed on my machine which is windows 10*** Probably means you have to manually setup the include path for your compiler to add wherever openssl is installed.

Comment: I installed openssl and set the environment variables . Now what should i do other than adding environment variables to tell my toolchain to find the openssl header files

Comment: @SnooBie again, that is very specific to the particular toolchain you are using. Please refer to your toolchain's documentation.